# Azure Cognitive Search - Error using GeographyPoint

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Using Azure Cognitive Search and specifying a GeographyPoint field like this:

```
[SearchableField(IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true)]
public GeographyPoint geoPoint { get; set; }
```

And them initializing it like this:

```
double lat = ... 
double lng = ...
doc.geoPoint = GeographyPoint.Create(lat, lng);
```

Returns the error (when the method CreateOrUpdateIndex is used):

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'The request is invalid. Details:
> definition : The searchable field 'geoPoint' must be of type
> Edm.String or Collection(Edm.String).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types) says that the type Edm.GeographyPoint is supported.
Anyone knows the reason for this error?

We already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566493/spatial-search-in-azure-search-net-client-api), and our implementation seens right.
We are using Azure Cognitive Search [SDK 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk#about-version-11).

We expected that the creation of the index would work with the GeographyPoint field. We read the documentation and review our approach and found no error in our implementation.

Comment: can you provide some more detailed code that can help in reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Edm.GeographyPoint` data type is supported however a field of this data type is not searchable. Only fields with `Edm.String` and `Collection(Edm.String)` data types are searchable. This is why you are getting this error.

Note that `searchable` indicates whether it's usable for full-text search. Even though point fields cannot be searchable, you can still mark them as filterable and/or sortable and use them for geo-filters (e.g. distance or bounding box predicates) or for sorting.

Please see REST API documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index#-field-definitions-.

To fix the error, make this field non-searchable.